# How to deal with unencoded URL redirects to my website correctly?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, drupal-8, cleverreach

We are using CleverReach to redirect people to our website after they have double opt-in their mail account. We redirect the email as a query parameter to our website, like: `example.com/thanks?email=foo@bar.com` (by setting up a redirect in the CleverReach backend like `example.com/thanks?email={EMAIL}`). Apparently, the email parameter doesnt get urlencoded by cleverreach.

Now, in Drupal, if the URL is like so: `example.com/thanks?email=hello+world@bar.com` and using this code:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
$email = $request->query->get('email');
```

`$email` is `hello world@bar.com`. Now, I dont know what the correct processing is here. Obviously, I cant tell CleverReach to urlencode their redirects beforehand. I dont even know if that would be best practice or if I need to imlement something...

The only thing I found out is that `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the "real" string, which I can urlencode and then redirect, and then, by reading the query params, urldecode them. But I feel like I am missing some crucial inbuilt functionality.

## TL;DR

If a website redirects to my website using not urlencoded query params, how do I read them?

## My current approach:

```
<?php
public function redirectIfIllegalUri() {
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $email = $request->query->get('email', '');

  $needsRedirect = (false !== strpos($email, ' ') || false !== strpos($email, '@'));

  if ($needsRedirect && isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && false !== strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'email=')) {

    $sqs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $sqs = htmlspecialchars($sqs);
    $sqs = filter_var($sqs, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sqs = filter_var($sqs, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    $sqs = urldecode($sqs);
    $sqs = explode('&', $sqs);

    foreach ($sqs as $queryParam) {
      if (false === strpos($queryParam, 'email=')) continue;
      $values = explode('=', $queryParam);
      $email = $values[1];
    }

    $emailEncoded = urlencode($email);
    $query = $request->query->all();
    $query['email'] = $emailEncoded;

    $refreshUrl = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
    $refreshUrl->setOptions([
      'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $response = new RedirectResponse($refreshUrl->toString(), 301);
    $response->send();
    return;
  }
}

$request = \Drupal::request();
$email = urldecode($request->query->get('email', false));
```

[drupal request() docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/class/Request/8.2.x)

Comment: i dont quite get it, `?email=hello+world@bar.com` _is_ the url-encoded form of `hello world@bar.com` which rather is an invalid e-mail adress right?

Comment: @johnSmith well if its encoded, why does `$_GET['email']` return `hello world@bar.com` then? i think the encoded version replaces `+` with `%2B`. also, this is a valid email address actually

Comment: then i dont understand your question, if `$_GET['email']` always returns urldecoded you hsould be fine, not ? What error dou you have when email is not url-encoded ?

Comment: as i said, `$_GET['email']` returns `hello world@bar.com` while I expect `hello+world@bar.com`

Comment: The issue has to be addressed from the ClerverReach side : whether this link is in the email template or the final confirmation page template, one should be able to properly escape that part of the url. Where is the code responsible for generating this link for new subscribers ?

Comment: I also don't really understand. If you know that CleverReach doesn't encode the email address properly, then you can write the enpdoint that you make them redirect your users to in such a way that it handles a not properly encoded email address, right? Or is this not just about email addresses?

Comment: @minitauros initially i wasnt even sure if i was correct about it not being encoded properly. i guess usually its not a problem, but the `+` char is an exception, as it seems

Comment: Admitted, it is a bit weird that a space does get converted to +, but an @ not to %40 (or whatever it is, don't know off the top of my head :)). Hope you fixed it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that the `+` will be treated as a space  when you get the value from `$_GET` global variable.

Currently in `PHP` doesn't exist a method that returns these values without `urldecoding` and you need to build a custom function to achieve what you are asking:

A simple function will return not encoded input is by using this function:

```
function get_params() {
    $getData = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $getParams = explode('&', $getData);

    $getParameters = [];
    foreach ($getParams as $getParam) {
        $parsed = explode('=', $getParam);
        $getParameters[$parsed[0]] = $parsed[1];
    }

    return $getParameters;
}
```

This solution can be used if you do not have any other option. By using this function you will always get the data encoded.

If you can encode the value from `cleverreach` then the best approach is to encode it there.

Encoding the value in `cleverreach` for email `hello+world@bar.com` will give you this url `example.com/thanks?email=hello%2Bworld%40bar.com` and in **$_GET** you will have the email containing the `+` sign.

Comment: well, thats pretty much what i got beforehand. im not sure whether this is really best practice, though. just reading out the query string seems very unsafe.

Comment: Yeap, that's why i have suggested to urlencode in cleverreach. In that way you will not have problems.